# How to take screenshot in Android Emulator (user pressing "power" + "vol down")?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I need to take a screenshot inside my app, so the image would be saved in Google Photos. All questions I see related to taking screenshot are basically about saving screenshot of your pc with an opened emulator. However I want to simulate taking a real screenshot by user (like if user pressed "power" + "vol down")

Comment: Use the media projection APIs.

Comment: @CommonsWare I would like to simulate user's behaviour, so it cannot be programmatical

Comment: "so it cannot be programmatical" -- that statement is the opposite of "I need to take a screenshot inside my app".

Comment: @CommonsWare screenshot must be taken by user, and not by a program. You mentioned media projection API, which shows the way to take screenshot with Kotlin code (programmatically)

Comment: Correct, but "I need to take a screenshot **inside my app**" indicates that you *want* a programmatic solution. I do not understand how "inside my app" can mean anything other than a programmatic solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare how would you rephrase it, so it would mean a screenshot by user and not programmaticly and also not a screenshot of the emulator (meaning screenshot of pc screen with opened emulator) ?

Comment: Looks like Paul is looking for a way to emulate pressing "power" + "vol down" to trigger a screen shot like you can do on a physical device but instead via via adb (because from within an app this is AFAIK not possible).

Comment: @Robert that's right, I wasn't able to press down two buttons at the same time on the emulator